# How to set start parameters and different credentials for multiple instance in windows service installer?

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services, installation

I write a windows service and a installer project using C# with Visual Studio 2010.

This service will get some data from database.

There're more than one database with different windows domain login account.

**I want the installer pass the connection string as a parameters to each service instance**, each instance has different service name.

I look into MSDN and see `OnStart(string[] args)`. It needs to write register keys to make a service run with parameters automatically. **Is there any other easy ways to do that?**

Beside, I set username and password value to null in my installer project. A dialog will be promoted during the installation. **But it's only once. I want to set different credentials for each service instance. So it needs to be promotes many times.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather install as many instances as you require and use the `connectionStrings` section in your config file.

I have a generic host (see: http://shuttle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ba9750ca1f7a#Shuttle.Core%2fsource%2fShuttle.Core.Host%2fHost.cs) that allows you to easily implement multiple instances of services or run your code as a console application.

HTH